# User defined template completion with symbols instead of placeholder

Tags: front-end, autocomplete, templates

In *Mathematica* 9, the following `usage` definition generates the corresponding template (obtained by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> after typing out `myfunction` in the front end):

```
myfunction::usage = "myfunction[{a,b,c},PackageObject[d,e,f]] returns the result of processing {a,b,c} with packageobject[d,e,f].";
```

[image: version 9.0.1 template]

In *Mathematica* 8, 10, and 11, the same `usage` yields a template in which a placeholder appears for `PackageObject`.

[image: version 8, 10, 11 template]

What do I need to do on versions 8, 10 and 11 so that the template for `myfunction` looks like that in *Mathematica* 9?

---

**Edit**

I discovered that in *Mathematica* 10 and above, `usage` messages with built-in symbols actually behave as intended.  Observe:

```
yourFunction::usage = "yourFunction[Cos[x],Sin[x],expr] replaces expr with its trigonometric counterpart."
```

[image]

The symbols `Cos` and `Sin` are correctly displayed, and do not appear as placeholders.

**Edit #2**

And then I found that if you first create the symbol in the `` System` `` context like this,

```
System`PackageObject
```

then the template is created as intended:

[image]

I think I'm getting close to the answer.  Apparently, the template creation system is looking for symbols in the `` System` `` context.  Is there any way to modify this behavior???

Comment: You can try to write to the support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The V9 behavior is technically buggy, although it is perhaps worth revisting.

One solution to your problem is to explictly include the context in the usage. For example:

```
myfunction::usage="myContext`myfunction[{a,b,c},myContext`PackageObject[d,e,f]]"
```

It has the downside of not looking as pretty (either in the template or when inserted), but it (a) solves the problem of the bad Placeholder insertion, and (b) ensures that the symbol will always be created in the correct context.

If you really want to solve this, you can poke around the `FE` context, in particular the function `insertTagBox` which inserts the actual place holders.  As usual, this unsupported, may eat your homework, and may break in a future release.

Comment: Thank you for your tips!  After playing around with the ``FE` `` context, I found that if I set ``FE`systemQ[FE`s_] := 
 StringMatchQ[Quiet[Check[Context[FE`s], ""]], "System`" | "myContext`"]``, then I get exactly the behavior I need.